# Как прочитать строку из консоли целиком, а не только первое слово?

Tags: c++

Необходимо считать строку формата: Фамилия "пробел" Инициалы(С.Н.) "пробел" две цифры 
пример: `Иванов П.С. 57`
Ниже приведен пример кода:

```
string s;

cin >> s;
cout << s.substr(s.size() - 1, 2);
```

Comment: И в чём заключается вопрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот это

```
cin >> s;
```

считает только первое слово. Если вам нужна *строка*, то читайте ее как

```
getline(cin,s);
```

(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)