# Как пропустить пробел в анализе текста на буквы

Tags: c++

написал такой кодик для лабораторки:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string text;

   cout << "Vvedite text:" << endl;
   cin >> text;
   int i = 0;

   for (i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
   {
               
       if (int(text[i]) == 43)
       {
           if (int(text[i - 1]) == 43)
           {
               if (int(text[i - 2]) == 67)
               {
                  
                   cout << "C++ vpervie vstrechaetsa na indekse '" << i-1 << "' .";
                   break;
                   
               }
           
           }
       }
   }
   cout << "C++ ne vstrechaetsa v texte.";
}
```

Если весь текст написал без пробелов, то работает отлично
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если написать пробел, то дальше пробела цикл уже не пойдет, хотел бы спросить совета, как при встрече в тексте пробела, заканчивать текущую "проходку" цикла, и начинать следующую?
Вот как я пытался сделать:

```
char space = ' ';
...
 if (text[i] == space || int(text[i]) == 32)
        {continue;} //то есть при соблюдение условия, мы начинаем новую проходку, но уже с i++
```

Ссылка на код и онлайн компилятор: [ССЫЛКА](https://cpp.sh/?source=%23include%20%3Cstring%3E%0D%0A%23include%20%3Ciostream%3E%0D%0Ausing%20namespace%20std%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aint%20main()%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20string%20text%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cout%20%3C%3C%20%22Vvedite%20text%3A%22%20%3C%3C%20endl%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cin%20%3E%3E%20text%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20int%20i%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20text.length()%3B%20i%2B%2B)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(int(text%5Bi%5D)%20%3D%3D%2043)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(int(text%5Bi%20-%201%5D)%20%3D%3D%2043)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(int(text%5Bi%20-%202%5D)%20%3D%3D%2067)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cout%20%3C%3C%20%22C%2B%2B%20vpervie%20vstrechaetsa%20na%20indekse%20%27%22%20%3C%3C%20i-1%20%3C%3C%20%22%27%20.%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cout%20%3C%3C%20%22C%2B%2B%20ne%20vstrechaetsa%20v%20texte.%22%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/657418/195342

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как прочитать строку из консоли целиком, а не только первое слово?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/657418/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be)

Answer (score -1):

Заменил cin на getline - заработало, спасибо комментатору.